# Как создать поле ввода во view, если условие выполняется. ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Хочу реализовать такой алгоритм.

Есть класс Properties

у него есть свойство которое ссылается на категории

так же есть поле SerealNumber

```
 public class Properties : Entity
    {
        [Display(Name = "Название")] public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Категория")] 
    public Category Category { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Так же есть метод Create

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bindя("Name,CategoryId,SerialNumber,Id")] Properties properties)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(properties));
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "Id", "Name", properties.CategoryId);

            return View(properties));
        }
```

Мне нужно сделать так, что при условии если категория равна к примеру (Бытовая техника), то появлялось поле SerialNumber, если к примеру (сантехника), то поле не появлялось.

Как это можно реализовать?

Я пробовал передавать значение

```
var comp = _context.Categories.Where(n => n.Name == "Компьютеры");
ViewData["Category"] = comp;
```

И потов в view

делал так

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
            {
                    if (ViewBag.Category == "Бытовая техника")
                    {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SerialNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SerialNumber" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="SerialNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
                    }
            }
```

Так же пробовал просто во view так

```
@if (Model.Properties .Name == "Бытовая техника")
                 {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SerialNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SerialNumber" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="SerialNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
                 }
```

Голову сломал, не могу понять как реализовать. Вроде простая задача, но не как не могу решить.

Comment: Input для serial number вывести целиком как есть, но скрыть через установку css-свойств  visible:hidden или display:none (лучше со всем div'ом), сделать необязательным полем. Написать javascript, будет менять видимость элемента в зависимости от выбранных занчений в категории. При необходимости строгой валидации сделать на сервере кастомный валидатор модели.

Comment: @A K Спасибо за ответ. Я не понял `вывести целиком как есть` что здесь имеется ввиду?. А, без javascript это можно сделать?

Comment: Нет, без javascript нельзя. Ну или как "нельзя" -- можно, но настолько извращённым способом, что так никто не делает. Например: у вас две разные формы, одна с серийным номером, другая без -- и если начато заполнение в одной, но вдруг был выбран такой пункт, что нужно показать -- идёт редирект на другую страницу, а введённое сохраняется в локалсторадж или GET/POST параметры. Вам не стало наглядно видно, что такой способ неудобен и чреват разными багами?

Comment: "Вывести целиком" - это я видимо писал в задумчивости и почему-то подумал, что у вас серийный номер не Input, а select. Потому что обычно ваше задание звучит как задача о двух селектах, типа: при выборе страны Россия показывать select в котором ввести область. Извините, что невольно запутал вас.

Comment: @A K Да, с javascript было бы лучше. Но я с яjavascript вой не очень на ты! Если честно то даже не знаю с чего начать скрипт!

Comment: Все когда-то были не очень на ты, просто кто-то так и остался потому что не тренировался или изредка копипастил готовый код. А вы сначала попробуйте у любого input прописать `onclick="alert('wow!')"`, потом научиться в онклик прописывать функцию и в ней уже делать alert. Когда получится - начните по клику вызывать функции jquery (он же у вас из коробки в asp.net включен) и по клику делать [hide и show](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_hide_show.asp). Любую, даже самую сложную задачу можно разбить на независимые блоки и они будут настолько просты, что легко сделать. Д - декомпозиция! )

Comment: @AK да вы правы конечно! И процесс двигается. Просто пока с javascript редко сталкиваюсь! Основы то знаю. Я больше парюсь не как функцию создать, а как сконектить её с полем к примеру категории. Onclic нужно у поля категории делать и его передавать в функцию по id="serialNumber". А, какое поле передать в метод для сравнения. Поле id же. И что должен вернуть? Значение true. И в условии во view если true то поле инпут появляеться. Если нет то поле не появляеться. Правельно я мыслю?

Comment: Нет, в данном случае вам нужно использовать не OnClick, а OnChange у select'а и внутри ончейндж нужно читать какой у this селекта выбран пункт (сравнивать его с id бытовой техники). Если равен - то для $('#div_s_inputom') делать .show а иначе делать .hide. Делов-то на полчаса разобраться. Гуглится всё с полпинка по тривиальным запросам типа "jquery get selected option value" - и всё это сто лет как отвечено на stackoverflow. Просто нужно аккуратно всё собрать воедино.

Comment: @AK примерно понял! Хотя врядли я провожусь 30 мин. ! Спасибо! Буде пробовать!